# jquery ajax request failing in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a ajax request working in safari,FF and Chrome but not in IE6.I get the error message and the xhr.statusText is **unknown**.I know I should be ditching IE6 but its in the requirements list so I'm helpless.If anyone has a solution to please lemme know.

Thanks

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "vMenu.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success')        ;
        }
    });
```

the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="vMenu.xsl"?>
<vMenuList>
    <menu loc="menu1.htm">menu1</menu>
    <menu loc="menu2.htm">menu2</menu>  
    <menu loc="menu3.htm">menu3</menu>  
    <menu loc="menu4.htm">menu4</menu>  
    <menu loc="menu5.htm">menu5</menu>  
    <menu loc="menu6.htm">menu6</menu>  
    <menu loc="menu7.htm">menu7</menu>  
    <menu loc="menu8.htm">menu8</menu>  
</vMenuList>
```

All the files are in the same folder

Comment: Can you tell me whether the request is reaching the server? and what is the content-type of the response?

Comment: What are the values of (xhr, status, errorThrown) and which jquery version are you using ?

Comment: @Christopher [objectError],parserError and Unknown and Im using jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the success with complete:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "vMenu.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText);
        },
        complete: function(data){
            alert('success');
        }
});
```

That should do the trick. For more info on why this occurs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Does your server send the appropriate "text/xml" content type header?